# indexOf() function not working on arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, indexof

I have two divs as shown below:

```
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

I created an array using these two divs:

```
var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
```

I also created a variable to represent the first div:

```
var div1 = document.querySelectorAll(".container")[0];
```

When I use `indexOf()` to get the index of the first div in the array, I get an error:

> containers.indexOf is not a function

Here is a snippet summarizing my problem:

```js
var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
var div1 = document.querySelectorAll(".container")[0];
containers.indexOf(div1); // returns the error
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a *NodeList*, not an array. You can convert the NodeList to an array by calling `Array.from(...)`.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` which doesn't have an `indexOf` method.

Comment: However, you can do `Array.prototype.indexOf.call(containers, div1)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a *NodeList*, not an array. You can convert the NodeList to an array by calling [`Array.from(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Answer (score 2):

Queryselectorall returns non-live node list. The indexOf method is not defined on that. More info is here

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

You could use Array.from() to convert to array and then use indexOf

Comment: `non-live === dead`? Or is "static" more PC? ;-)

Comment: That's what official documents say on MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll

Comment: @RobG it's more static rather than dead. :)

Comment: Was just having fun. ;-) Not to nit-pick, but the "official documentation" is the [*W3C Selectors API*](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall) which says "*The NodeList object returned by the querySelectorAll() method must be static, not live*".  MDN is a very useful resource, but it's a public wiki that is not normative. PS: MDN updated. ;-)